# "AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'next'" when trying to pop a None value in a Stack using a Linked List in Python

Tags: python-3.x, stack, singly-linked-list, attributeerror

Hey I'm trying to implement a pop function in my Stack. It works as long there are elements in the list. After that this error "AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'next'" comes up.

I tried to find the issue with the help of the debugger, but the only thing i found out is that the issue comes up at the third the pop function gets called. So at the time when it is empty.

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
        
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head
        
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self,top=None):
        self.ll = LinkedList(top)

    def push(self, new_element):
        "Push (add) a new element onto the top of the stack"
        if self.ll is None:
            self.ll = new_element
        else:
            current = new_element
            current.next = self.ll
            self.ll = new_element

    def pop(self):
        "Pop (remove) the first element off the top of the stack and return it"
        if self.ll is None:
            return None
        else:
            popped = self.ll
            self.ll = self.ll.next
            return popped
    
# Test cases
# Set up some Elements
e1 = Element(1)
e2 = Element(2)
e3 = Element(3)
e4 = Element(4)

# Start setting up a Stack
stack = Stack(e1)

# Test stack functionality
stack.push(e2)
stack.push(e3)
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop().value
print stack.pop()
stack.push(e4)
print stack.pop().value
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you omit the `LinkedList` layer in your push/pop logic -- it assumes that `ll` is a `Node` instance, but it is a `LinkedList`. There is no reference to `self.ll.head` in your code, while that is the only attribute that `self.ll` has.

It becomes apparent that this extra layer is just a nuisance, and it *would* have been more practical if indeed you could use the code as you did -- without this extra layer.

As a solution I would suggest that you make `Stack` a subclass of `LinkedList`, so that the level of `ll` disappears. Now replace all those `ll` with `head` and it will work:

```
class Stack(LinkedList):  # subclass
    # No need for an explicit constructor now
    
    def push(self, new_element):
        # Reference `head` instead of `ll` (which no longer exists)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_element
        else:
            current = new_element
            current.next = self.head
            self.head = new_element

    def pop(self):
        # ... Same here
        if self.head is None:
            return None
        else:
            popped = self.head
            self.head = self.head.next
            return popped
```